# Avoid using the !important css attribute for showing my container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I show/hide a container with boxes inside as showed below.

[image]

I use a simple mechanism with `toggleClass` to show/hide the container.

```
    $("#btn").click(
        function () {
            $("#switch-apps-panel").toggleClass('flex-apps-panel');
        }            
    );
```

The problem is I had to use the `important` attribute on the css and I prefer to avoid it.

```
.flex-apps-panel {
    display: flex !important;
}
```

Any help on slightly changing my code to avoid using the `important` attribute ?

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hg60e8gf/

Comment: make it more specific

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You defined `switch-apps-panel` as an ID. IDs are always higher ranked and more specific than class names.

In order to get rid of your `!important` statement, either change the ID to a class or make your selector more specific and add the ID selector to your `.flex-apps-panel` like this:

```
#switch-apps-panel.flex-apps-panel {
    display: flex;
}
```

Here I changed it to be a class:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#btn").click(
    function() {
      $(".switch-apps-panel").toggleClass('flex-apps-panel');
    }
  );
});
```

```css
.switch-apps-panel {
  display: none;
  z-index: 9999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 70px;
  left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #b6b6b6;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.flex-apps-panel {
  display: flex;
}

.box-1 {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.box-2 {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.box-3 {
  margin: 8px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
By default, boxes are hidden.

<button id="btn">Click here to show/hide boxes</button>

<div class="switch-apps-panel">
  <div class="box-1">
    <span>First</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <span>Second</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box-3">
    <span>Third</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: got burnt on this one, you guys answer so fast here :D. I suggest you do use only classes to apply style to HTML blocks. ID's is rarely used because of the unicity and priority on styling

Comment: Great ! Thanks for the info about difference of priority between classes and IDs.

Comment: I agree with @Alex ... try to only use classes for styles.

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase your selector's specificity. ID selectors have higher specificity than class selectors, so you can just try to select your ID with class like this:

```
#switch-apps-panel.flex-apps-panel {
    display: flex;
}
```

You can read more about specificity [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity), and also try to avoid styling by IDs in the future.